# Как вызвать событие вручную или как имитировать нажатие на кнопку

Tags: c#

Есть форма, на ней userControl который прилетает по dll, после выбора продукта с userControl, открываеться другая форма с дополнительными параметрами( у меня нет доступа к этой форме), на ней нажимаем кнопку принять, форма закрывается,  мы выходим из функции. Теперь мне нужно запустить другую функцию в этом же классе, можно запустить ее через нажатие на кнопку в первой форме, но мне нужно что бы эта функция запускалась автоматически. Тоесть нужно вызвать событие вручную .Как это сделать?

```
public partial class CatalogPaletteControl : UserControl
{
     public CatalogPaletteControl()
     {
        InitializeComponent(); 
     }
     private void CatalogPaletteControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //do something
     }
}
```

После загрузки  `CatalogPaletteControl_Load`  поток заканчиваеться, тоесть ничего больше не происходит. Где вызывать `button1_Click(null,null)`

Comment: Button_Click(name_of_button, new EventArgs())?

Comment: Вот как его вызвать не нажимая кнопки

Comment: WinForms? Поставьте метку.

Comment: Вы знаете как вызвать любой метод? Обработчик события — тот же метод.

Answer (score 2):

Обработчик события - это обычный метод. И вызвать его можно самым обычным способом.

Допустим, имеется такой метод-обработчик нажатия на кнопку

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some code
}
```

Вызываем его:

```
SomeButton_Click(null, null);
```

Здесь в качестве параметров передаются `null`.

Если в обработчике нужно знать, какая именно кнопка вызвала его, плюс нужно определённое значение аргументов события, то вызываем метод с параметрами:

```
SomeButton_Click(someButton, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Второй параметр можно явно создать: `new EventArgs()`.

---

У класса `Button` есть метод [PerformClick](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Button_PerformClick), можно использовать его:

```
someButton.PerformClick();
```

---

Ещё один вариант, вынести в отдельный метод код, содержащийся в обработчике события:

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWork();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // some code
}
```

И вызывать этот метод там, где нужно:

```
DoWork();
```

Естественно, добавляем параметры, если они нужны.

Этот способ более правильный с точки зрения архитектуры: отделяем код бизнес-логики от GUI.

Comment: как это вызвать я не понимаю  SomeButton_Click(null, null)

Comment: @Serg - `button1_Click(null, null);`

Comment: Если ее вызывать в середине метода private void CatalogPaletteControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) то мне это не подходит так  как мне нужно что загрузка формы завершилась, вернее что бы поток закончился